# I have a Joomla site with a j2store shopping cart on the home page. How I disable page caching of the shopping cart?

Tags: joomla

I noticed that the shopping cart only updates when I manually clear the page cache in the Joomla admin view.

In "System >> Global Configuration >> System", I have "Cache" set to "OFF - Caching disabled". Yet, every time I delete the "page" cache, and then revisit the home page, it is newly made in the page cache directory, with the latest shopping cart contents.

I would like to ideally cache the whole page, except for the shopping cart module. But, in the worst case, I would like to simply turn caching off *completely*.

Is there some other place in the Joomla settings where caching might be on, despite being clearly off on the global settings?

Thanks! I am new to Joomla and I hope that this is something simple.

Comment: Please check the caching option in module settings.

Comment: Thank you. Where could I find that?